# Searching for a value in a linked list stack

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stack

I am trying to write a search function for a linked list stack in java. I am having problems however as when I declare a temporary variable pointing to my head variable so I don't lose my actual stack of values when searching through, I am unable to invoke my topX and topY methods, and I am unsure as to why. What is causing this?

The error I get is  topX(MyNode) is undefined for the type MyNode.

My Code:

```
public class MyStack
{
  private MyNode head;

  public MyStack()
  {
    head = null;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    if (head == null)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public void push (int v1, int v2)
  {
    MyNode tmp = new MyNode (v1, v2);
    tmp.next = head;
    head = tmp;

  }

  public void pop()
  {
    head = head.next;
  }

  public int topX(MyNode node)
  {
    return node.x;
  }

  public int topY(MyNode node)
  {
    return node.y;
  }
   //THIS IS WHERE i get my error
  public boolean search(int v1, int v2, MyNode node){
    MyNode temp = node;
    //My problem is I can't even call this function
    while (temp.topX(node)!= v1 && temp.topY(node) != v2
           && temp.next!=null){
    temp = temp.next;
}
    }
}
//I declared MyNode seperately
class MyNode
{
  int x, y;

  MyNode next;

 MyNode (int v1, int v2)
 {
    x = v1;
    y = v2;
    next = null;

  }
}
}
```

Comment: `temp` is a `MyNode`, which does not have a method `topX`.  `MyStack` does, though.

Comment: remove temp.topX(node) and replace with topX(temp). Do the same for topY.